# uniform lower bound for integrals of almost everywhere positive function

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and let $f$ be a function defined on $\Omega$ which is positive almost everywhere.

Let $c$ be a fixed positive constant such that $c < m(\Omega)$, where $m(\Omega)$ denotes the Lebesgue measure of $\Omega$

Then, is it true that

> there exists a positive constant $M$ such that for any subset $V$ of $\Omega$ with $m(V) \geq c$, $$\int_V f(x)dx \geq M$$

Obviously, each  $\int_V f(x)dx$ is bounded away from zero, but is there a uniform bound?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Since the union of the sets $E_n=\{x:f(x)>1/n\}$ has measure $m(\Omega)$, there is $n$ such that $m(E_n)\ge m(\Omega)-c/2$. It follows that for every $V$ with $m(V)\ge c$, 
$$m(E_n\cap V) = m(E_n)+m(V)-m(E_n\cup V)\ge m(\Omega)-c/2+c-m(\Omega) = c/2$$
Hence, 
$$\int_V f\ge \int_{E_n\cap V} f\ge \frac{c}{2n}$$ which is a constant independent of $V$.